# how to center full length div horizontally in bootstrap without using ul li or navbar

Tags: asp.net, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design two  menu bar on same page first gray and second blue 
[image]
Now I have developed the blue toolbar which is working fine 
with following code below but now the problem is, i cannot use this (.navbar .nav > li > a) and similar classes for both menu bars because of the color and size. The main problem is i have to centered align the text with the width of website block. When i zoom by pressing control + mouse scroll gray bar should be centered align Any Idea how to fix this????

```
<style type="text/css">
    li a
    {
        font-size: 15pt;
    }

    .nav
    {
        min-width: 850px;
    }
    .navbar
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .navbar .nav
    {
        margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
    }
    .nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse
    {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus
    {
        background-color: #004a8f;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-inner
    {
        background-image: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #1276bc;
        min-height: 40px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #004a8f;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    }
    .navbar .nav > li > a
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        float: none;
        line-height: 19px;
        padding: 17px 21px 0 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: none;
        height: 30px;
        width: 116px;
        border-right: 1px solid #6992cc;
    }
    .navbar .nav > li > a:hover
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: none;
        float: none;
        line-height: 19px;
        padding: 17px 21px 0 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #004a8f;
        height: 30px;
        width: 116px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-TopPanel
    {
        background-color: transparent;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        height: 30px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-BottomPanel
    {
        background-color: #1276bc;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        max-width: 760px;
        padding-left: 8px;
    }
    ul, ol
    {
        /*  padding-left:18%;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        padding-right:5px;*/
    }
    .lock
    {
        /* text-decoration: none;*/
        color: gray;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    .Unlock
    {
        color: #1276BC;
        font-weight: bolder; /*text-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);*/
    }
</style>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container navbar-inner-BottomPanel">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="Default.aspx">
                                <img id="Img1" style="margin-top: -15px; height: 25px;" runat="server" src="../images/logoheader.png"
                                    alt="Home" /></a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Play</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Teams</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to center your website, you can do this :

```
<style>
    .container
    {
        width: 1000px; /* set the width that's you want */
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

and under your `div .row-fluid` :

```
<div class="Greygradiant" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
    <div class="container">
         <!-- your content -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it's help !

Comment: Sorry it didnt helped i cannot fix width to 1000pixel if you zoom (i want to open my site im ipads) then the gray bar is not in full width

Comment: i have made some changes in your code now it worked for me thanks to you @joffrey kem